# Add text on top of an image and place them side by side

Tags: html, css

I want to add text on top of two images and then place them side by side. I tried do this in the following way:

```css
#main {
  position: fixed;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#front-header {
  font-family: "Linux Biolinum";
  font-size: 42pt;
  line-height: 0pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
#PI {
  font-family: "Linux Libertine";
  font-size: 22pt;
  line-height: 0pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
#copyright {
  font-family: "Latin Modern Mono";
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 0pt;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-align: center;
}
#meerkat {
  width: 18cm;
  height: 14cm;
}
#salt {
  width: 17.5cm;
  height: 14cm;
}
#figu {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 30px;
}
#container {
  height: 17.5cm;
  width: 14cm;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
#images {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#text {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
.image {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  /* optional */
}
.image .text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  /* in conjunction with left property, decides the text     position */
  left: 10px;
  width: 300px;
  /* optional, though better have one */
}
```

```html
<body style="            height: 723.09px;">
  <p id="front-header">Learning HTML</p>
  <p id="PI">Author:TH</p>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
  <div>
    <img title="MeerKAT" alt="MeerKAT" id="meerkat" src="meerkat.jpg" border="0">&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <div style="background-image:url('SALT-1.jpg');background-repeat:no-repeat;height:20cm;width:20cm;">
      <h1 style="color:white;">Hello World!.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>
    <p id="copyright">Created Today</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

I want to add text on top of the figures named "meerkat.jpg" & "salt-1.jpg". After that I want to place them side by side.

Please suggest. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tanvir, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you convert your code into a Code Snippet? Thanks! See also https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Thanks @Roy I have converted the code into a Code Snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions to achieve this and this is my take. I make use of the `display: flex;` property that is being explained at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes). Examining the code in your question, I expect that you don't have that much experience in CSS, so I got rid of all the code and made a clean example.

When you set an image as `background-image`, you can just add an `<hX>` element inside of it to add the text on top of the image.

Another solution I provided is in the second row and makes use of `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;` together with an *inline image*. Setting the container to `relative` and the text that's inside of it to `absolute` will only affect the text *inside* the div.

You *could* also use `float`, but this can cause problems to your layout.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: 100%;
}
.image-wrapper {
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg');
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  /* Only to show that there are two images */
}
.image-wrapper h1 {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
}
.container-position {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.image-wrapper-position {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  width: 50%;
}
.image-wrapper-position h1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <h1>This is text</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <h1>This is text on top of image</h1>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="container container-position">

  <div class="image-wrapper-position">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg" />
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper-position">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AzeiaRY.jpg" />
    <h1>Hello world</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.Yes, I am learning CSS and how to work in HTML.  What if the two images are different? Say i want text on top of the second image only. Will then both remain side by side?

Comment: If I change the image, it is stretched. How to make it centered or fit?
Will using `background-position=center center;` work?

Comment: I could work out all the above problems. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Tanvir The images will stay side by side when one of the images doesn't have text. If the answer helped you out, please mark it as approved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code as a guide for your website. Alter the width and height in `<img>` to suit you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .floating-box {
    display: inline-block;
        float: left;
        width: 500;
        height: 500;
        margin: 50px;
        border: 1px solid 0;  
    }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h2>Text appearing above images</h2>

    <div class="floating-box"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:500px;height:250px;">
    </div>
    <div class="floating-box"> <img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg" alt="HTML5 Icon" style="width:500px;height:250px;">
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this does not put the text on top of the image.

Comment: Ohh, my bad. I misinterpreted the question!